# CompareValidator to validate two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, comparevalidator

Hi all I am having my date format in the following format `dd-MMM-yy` I am using compare validator to validate the dates as follows

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpDates" runat="server" ControlToValidate="StartDate"
                      SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToCompare="EndDate"
                      ErrorMessage="EndDate must be greater than StartDate"
                      Display="None" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                      ValidationGroup="vg" Type="Date"                           
                      CultureInvariantValues="true">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

But this is not working as per required so can some one help me how Can I validate the dates in the required format

Comment: You can use a `CalendarExtender` and set it's Format property

Comment: Hi I am using Devexpress controls here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, here we use the Ajax calander control to get the input in dd/mm/yyyy format and then use the compare validator

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtStart_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtStart">
            </cc1:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToCompare="txtEnd" ControlToValidate="txtStart" 
                ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"></asp:CompareValidator>

        </div>
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtEnd_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtEnd">
            </cc1:CalendarExtender>
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remodify the code like this

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpDates" runat="server" ControlToValidate="StartDate"
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToCompare="EndDate"
                  ErrorMessage="EndDate must be greater than StartDate"
                  Operator="LessThan"
                  ValidationGroup="vg" Type="Date"                           
                  CultureInvariantValues="true"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CompareValidator` does not work for `dd/mm/yyyy` format by default,so you need to explicitly change the `Culture` property of the page to en-GB in the page directive of the `ASP.Net Web Page`  or you can add it in `webconfig`

At **Page Level**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="_Default" 
    Culture = "en-GB" %>
```

At **Webconfig**:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" 
  responseEncoding="utf-8"
  culture="en-GB" 
 uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this method now this works fine for **dd-mm-yyyy** format

in web.config file

```
<system.web>
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" /></system.web>
```

upon updating this in .aspx page

add **Culture = "en-GB"**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="filename.aspx.cs" Inherits="<%--your backend code--%>"   Culture = "en-GB"  %>
```

now add CompareValidator to the comparing dates

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ValidationGroup = "Date" ForeColor = "Red" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "startdate" ControlToCompare = "enddate" Operator = "LessThan" Type = "Date" ErrorMessage="Start date must be less than End date."></asp:CompareValidator>
```